# Play framework db action after simple action

Tags: scala, playframework

So, basically what I want to do with play framework is:

1. check if user has logged in cookie
2. if user has logged in cookie fetch the record from the database

Code:

```
def allSamplesJson = Action { implicit request =>
  request.session.get("l").map { value =>
    value match {
      case "i" => DBAction { conn =>
        implicit val dbs = conn.dbSession
        val all = models.CodeSampleTable.allSamples()
        Ok(Json.toJson(all))
      }
      case _ => Unauthorized(unautStr)
    }
  }.getOrElse {
    Unauthorized(unautStr)
  }
}
```

Basically, I don't want to even touch database/open connection etc. if user is not authorized to fetch json records. The code above doesn't work (doesn't compile). How do I accomplish that?

This is the error:
[image: Compile error]

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work? Unauthorized users have access? Authorized users don't have access? Problem aside, I'd consider using an established authentication system: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24140660/authentication-in-play-2-3-x/24146143#24146143

Comment: Well I mean it doesn't compile. I just want to make it so that if user doesn't have cookie he wouldn't get json records from the database, so, I want to avoid DB connection altogether if that's the case. The problem is not "it semantically doesn't work", problem is it doesn't compile. I want to use DBAction inside simple Action

Comment: What is the compile error?

Comment: @m-z added screenshot to post.

Comment: @VanillaFace if you're using Slick, why not just use the [DB wrapper](https://github.com/playframework/play-slick/wiki/Usage#db-wrapper) to obtain a session? There's no need to nest actions as you're attempting (which won't compile since one branch of your match returns `Action[AnyContent]` and the other `Result`.)

Comment: @VanillaFace something like this: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d032d27291d17a536727

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't wrap a `DBAction` within another `Action` like that, because `DBAction` doesn't return a `Result`, it probably returns something like `Action[A]`. This means that you're trying to return mixed types within the higher level `Action` (`Result` and `Action[A]`), so the compiler infers the return type to be `Object`, when it's supposed to be `Result`.

As @Mikesname suggests, you need to replace `DBAction` with `DB.withSession`, which will provide the database session you need, and allow you to return the correct type:

```
DB.withSession { conn =>
    val all = models.CodeSampleTable.allSamples()
    Ok(Json.toJson(all))
}
```