# RESTful app with Play Framework Java

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, playframework

I would like to create RESTful Java app using Play Framework and Akka. I have already done basic Play tutorial, but I want to create separated front end and back end. How can I start? What are good principles of making app with Akka? Have you got any advices, books, tutorials? I have some knowledge in FE technologies, such as: AngularJS, Javascript, Bootstrap etc.

Currently I have troubles with authentication...

Comment: I'd start with the examples in https://www.lightbend.com/activator/templates.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of book-references on the [Play website](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Home). If you are looking for a general introduction to the play framework (including some akka), this should help you get started: [Reactive Web Applications](https://www.manning.com/books/reactive-web-applications)

As far as authentication is concerned, that topic has been discussed before: [Authentication in Play 2.3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24140660/1080523)